# Assistance needed with Task.ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Maybe I am missing something petty (will remove post if that is the case). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with this .ContinueWith() ? I do not see the result printed in the screen.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => { return Sum(5); });
    t.Start();
    t.Wait();
    t.ContinueWith((task) => { Console.WriteLine(task.Result); });
    //Console.WriteLine(t.Result); //this works

    Console.Read();
}

public static int Sum(int n)
{
    return 50;//stub result
}
```

Comment: Just compiled and ran your code, it works perfectly. Please add more Information about your `Sum()` method

Comment: Hmmm.. per Peter Ritche's answer, it could be because your machine was able to create the .ContinueWith() task faster than mine. I am running the same code for Sum().

Comment: @AntonyThomas It's basically random whether the continue has time to run on not.  Run it a few times and eventually you'd probably see no "50" in the console...

Answer (score 3):

You're application is probably exiting before you continuation is run.  If you put a breakpoint at end end of Main, you're stopping all threads while at that breakpoint and if the continuation hasn't run yet, it won't be allowed to run until you exit (and probably lose the output).

Try the following to see what happens:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => { return Sum(5); });
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();
            t.ContinueWith((task) => { Console.WriteLine(task.Result); });
            //Console.WriteLine(t.Result); //this works
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: It works!!
Explain this scenario:
If I comment .ContinueWith() and replace with Console.WriteLine(t.Result), it shows me the result.Why?? Could it be because creating a new task and then displaying result takes more time than just priting the result right away?

Comment: Thats because `Console.WriteLine` is blocking, which means it stops the code execution until you hit ENTER. If you use `Task`s, they will run on a seperate thread and will NOT BLOCK the execution of your code. So the application starts and ends before `WriteLine` will be called on the second thread. But even if it would be called, the application would exit, cause it will terminate after the first (main) thread terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand everything, except for the blocking part of Console.WriteLine(). Why should I hit an ENTER when using Console.WriteLine()? It just prints and exits right?

Comment: Using Console.WriteLine means the process stays running until you press enter.  This allows the asynchronous task you've created with ContinueWith time to run to completion and not be aborted by the process existing before it has time to exit.  normally, your application would be busy doing other things rather than exiting right after calling ContinueWith so you wouldn't need Console.ReadLine.